# Is it normal all testnet p2wsh cosigners have same master public key?

Tags: electrum

Created a testnet p2wsh Electrum multisig 2 of 3 wallet.

When I click on the radio buttons in `Wallet/Information`, all cosigners have same `Vpub` master public key. Normal?

Asking because I am trying out Electrum Personal Server and getting the following error.

> WARNING:2019-06-28 08:15:00,335: Address not known to server,
>   hash(address) =
>   d***********. This
>   means Electrum is requesting information about addresses that are
>   missing from Electrum Personal Server's configuration file.

The EPS `config.ini` comments mention the following format for 2 or 3 wallets but when I use `2 Vpub Vpub Vpub` the `first 3 addresses of each master public key` don’t match the ones I see in Electrum. Help!

> multisig_wallet = 2 xpub661MyMwAqRbcFseXCwRdRVkhVuzEiskg4QUp5XpUdNf2uGXvQmnD4zcofZ1MN6Fo8PjqQ5cemJQ39f7RTwDVVputHMFjPUn8VRp2pJQMgEF xpub661MyMwAqRbcFseXCwRdRVkhVuzEiskg4QUp5XpUdNf2uGXvQmnD4zcofZ1MN6Fo8PjqQ5cemJQ39f7RTwDVVputHMFjPUn8VRp2pJQMgEF xpub661MyMwAqRbcFseXCwRdRVkhVuzEiskg4QUp5XpUdNf2uGXvQmnD4zcofZ1MN6Fo8PjqQ5cemJQ39f7RTwDVVputHMFjPUn8VRp2pJQMgEF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not normal, each cosigner should have a unique master public key.

There is a [reported](https://github.com/spesmilo/electrum/issues/4777) bug in Electrum 3.3.6 that causes the issue on macOS.

Until a fix is pushed to production, it’s possible to get master public keys using the Electrum console (View/Show Console).

```
[k.xpub for k in wallet.get_keystores()]
```